# Clearing javascript canvas lineto with intersecting lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas which has some lines drawn by mouse movement. I want the line to only last for a few seconds before removing itself. A bit like swirling a ribbon around where it has a set length.
I am using lineTo to draw the lines in the canvas. I referenced a bit of the code from here.

**The problem**

I can clear the line by using clearRect() but this literally clears everything and the problem is that if the line intersects it clears the intersecting area too.
here is my Fiddle click and drag inside the bottom right box:

http://jsfiddle.net/m2K5h/

clear rect would give me this:
[image]

**In Summary**

clearRect just wipes everything, I want to dynamically 'un draw' the line so it has a lifetime. And I can't for the life of me find something to do it....

Any help would be amazing!!!!

Comment: for the record: you should never do something like this: `brush = eval("new " + BRUSHES[0] + "(context)");` eval is in general evil, there's nearly nothing you can't do without using eval. the above example is equivalent to `brush = BRUSHES[0](context)`

Comment: yeah I referenced the source from somewhere, where there were a lot of different brushes. There's a lot of code cleanup and rewriting I'm doing. Eval has saved my bacon a few times I have to say..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The canvas is a bitmap surface.  Nothing in the canvas could indicate that your line has crossed itself, other than the pixel values.

In order to have a line un-draw itself, you need to store all the coordinates for the line as it is drawn.  When it is time for the line to un-draw itself, you start an animation where every frame you clear the canvas and redraw a shrinking portion of the line.

## [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LRu9w/6/)

If you have anything else of significant complexity that you wouldn't want to erase and redraw rapidly, put that in a second canvas behind the first.

Comment: Voting up!! nice reference, really helpful, that's what I'm after. I'm a massive hater of layered canvases in generally. Especially as this is just one layer of a really complex DOM structured project, so I need to keep the DOM overhead down as much as possible.